# Linking Java Script and html-- Script (javascript) that shuffles the list of items (html)...works on here but not locally when I try to run

Tags: javascript, html

Linking Java Script and html-- Script (javascript) that shuffles the list of items (html)...works on here but not locally when I try to run

The code works when I use the console on this website when I went to post the code,but when I run through notepad++ in chrome...The program does not work. I am not sure why it would appear to work on here, but not on my local machine?

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var $nodes = $("#Items").find("li");
    shuffle($nodes, "Switch");
    $("#Items").append($nodes);
});
  
  
//Function that will shuffle only your switchable elements.
function shuffle(nodes, switchableSelector) {
    var length = nodes.length;
    
    //Create the array for the random pick.
    var switchable = nodes.filter("." + switchableSelector);
    var switchIndex = [];
    
    $.each(switchable, function(index, item) {
       switchIndex[index] = $(item).index(); 
    });

    //The array should be used for picking up random elements.
    var switchLength = switchIndex.length;
    var randomPick, randomSwap;
    
    for (var index = length; index > 0; index--) {
        //Get a random index that contains a switchable element.
        randomPick = switchIndex[Math.floor(Math.random() * switchLength)];
        
        //Get the next element that needs to be swapped.
        randomSwap = nodes[index - 1];
        
        //If the element is 'not switchable', ignore and continue;
        if($(randomSwap).hasClass(switchableSelector)) {
            nodes[index - 1] = nodes[randomPick];
            nodes[randomPick] = randomSwap;
        }
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>List of Items</h2>
<ul id="Items">
  <li class="Switch">Item 1</li>
  <li class="Switch">Item 2</li>
  <li class="Switch">Item 3</li>
  <li class="Switch">Item4</li>
  <li class="Switch">Item 5</li>
  <li class="Switch">Item 6</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Shuffle" />
```

Comment: Does the console give any errors when your run it? It might not be loading at all, try adding `console.log("Script Loaded");` at the top of the script file.

Comment: that appears to be the issue..what would the fix be

Comment: is the `html` file and  the `listscripts.js` in the same folder?

Comment: Make sure your script file is named `listscript.js` and is in the same directory as the html file. Sometimes things get saved as `listscript.js.txt` so turn on view file extension in the windows file explorer

Comment: Either put HTML & JS code in same file or put both the files at same location. This should solve your problem

Comment: The files are located in the same folder..were they linked correctly?

Comment: I chcked developer tools and the script is loaded...it is not executing though

Comment: the console has console.log("Script Loaded"); portion I added to the top

Answer (score 1):

It is the order of things: your code snippet tries to hook the click handler on the button right when it loads. However if you have the 'traditional' file layout, you have some `<script>` tag(s) first, and then the `<body>`. So when the `$(".btn").click(function(){...});` part runs, the given `<button>` does not exist (yet), and you do not even get an error, because it is a class-selector, which is perfectly valid to produce an empty result.

Put the `click`-binding part into a function, and call it from `onload`, then it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function startup(){
        $(".btn").click(function() {
          var $nodes = $("#Items").find("li");
          shuffle($nodes, "Switch");
          $("#Items").append($nodes);
        });
      }

      //Function that will shuffle only your switchable elements.
      function shuffle(nodes, switchableSelector) {
        /* unchanged */
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startup()">
    <h2>List of Items</h2>
    <ul id="Items">
      <!-- truncated as it is not an example which could run here anyway -->
    </ul>
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Shuffle" />
  </body>
</html>
```

On StackOverflow the code works, because the `<script>` part is located at the end of `<body>` (you can check it with right-click on your own example and "View frame source", at least in Chrome, but that is the browser you have mentioned). That is also a possible and legal layout, some people like it some others do not, it certainly cures this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may clear cache memory of chrome and run it again